# Return the args which are not passed as nil inside the function

Tags: dictionary, clojure, defn

```
(defn bar[{:keys [a b] :as args}] (prn "got" args))
```

If we are calling the above function as

```
(bar {:a 1})
```

it returns

```
{:a 1}
nil
```

I want to have

```
{:a 1 :b nil}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this can be done without changing the implementation of Clojure's destructuring code. Is below satisfactory?

```
user=> (defn bar [{:keys [a b]}] (prn "got" {:a a, :b b}))
#'user/bar
user=> (bar {:a 1})
"got" {:a 1, :b nil}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's worth the trouble, but you can get closer using the `vals->map` macro [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo):

```
(defn whiffer
  [{:keys [a b]}]
  (vals->map a b) )
```

with result:

```
(whiffer {:a 1, :b 2})  => {:a 1, :b 2}
(whiffer {:a 1})        => {:a 1, :b nil}
```